# How can I use Bitfields specifically for the following purpose

Tags: c++, bit-fields

for the purpose of learning efficient memory management I would like to know how it is possible to use individual Bit fields to represent the values of 8 bool values collectively, and how to evaluate and set each bit.

Reason is in my own program, which I wont paste because thousands of lines.
within class global scope, there are hundred or so, bools all required, this greatly effects FPS.

example:

```
       uint8_t b0:1, b1:1, b2:1, b3:1, b4:1, b5:1, b6:1, b7:1;

       if (!b0) { 
       // do something
       b0 = true; 
       }
```

Comment: Do note that accessing a bit is not a trivial thing and while you save space that comes with a increase cost in code complexity and often times speed.

Comment: Also note that std::vector<bool> is specialized to use only 1 bit for each value, so the work is already done for you.

Comment: Simply use bit manipulation.  Remember digital logic? On/Off (XOR). `b0 ^= 1` turns it On/Off

Comment: Thanks  @NathanOliver Yes I understand, code complexity is an issue doing so. Thankfully, its a single class of the entire program, where I wish to implement.

Comment: @Phil M Thanks, I will research.

Comment: Bitmasks > Bitfields. You can use an `enum` to define your bitfield values and standard binary math to compose them.

Comment: @tadman Thanks, it never occurred to me to take that approach, between the various replys here, looks as if there are a few common practices go about the task.

Answer (score 2):

Bit fields can only be specified for data members. From the very first line of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field :

> Declares a **class data member** with explicit size [...]

You would need to wrap your bit fields in a struct. Example :

```
#include <cstdint>
struct bool_pack {
    uint8_t b0 : 1, b1 : 1, b2 : 1, b3 : 1, b4 : 1, b5 : 1, b6 : 1, b7 : 1;
};

int main()
{
    bool_pack b = {};

    if (!b.b0) {
        // do something
        b.b0 = true;
    }
}
```

There is a more convenient standard library type [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) that you should consider using instead. Example :

```
#include <bitset>
int main()
{
    std::bitset<8> b;

    if (!b[0]) {
        // do something
        b[0] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks  for a really descent example on your part, I will look into it.